# Extend and Include

Tags: ruby, include

Rubymonk 4.1 entitled "The `included` Callback and the `extend` Method" is asking me to modify the module Foo in the following exercise so that when you include it in the class Bar, it also adds all the methods from ClassMethods into Bar as class methods.

```
module Foo
  module ClassMethods
    def guitar
      "gently weeps"
    end
  end
end

class Bar
  include Foo
end

puts Bar.guitar
```

Must define self.included(base) method in the module and extend the base with ClassMethods.

I've been tinkering around and can't figure it out.

Guidance please :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
module Foo
  def self.included(base)
    base.extend Foo::ClassMethods
  end

  module ClassMethods    
    def guitar
      "gently weeps"
    end
  end
end

class Bar
  include Foo
end

puts Bar.guitar
```

Answer (score 3):

You define a method called `self.included(base)`.

```
module Foo
  def self.included(base)
    base.extend(ClassMethods)
  end

  module ClassMethods    
    def hey
      p "hey!"
    end
  end
end

class Bar
  include Foo
end

puts Bar.hey #=> hey!
```

This works because .included is called anytime a module is included. Inside `.included` your code is extending the base class with the methods from `ClassMethods`.

John Nunemaker has an excellent post with details here:

[Include vs Extend in Ruby](http://www.railstips.org/blog/archives/2009/05/15/include-vs-extend-in-ruby/).

See the bottom of the post for the answer to this question in greater detail. It's a great read.

Answer (score -1):

You need to use `ActiveSupport::Concern` http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Concern.html

```
module Foo
  def self.included(base)
    base.extend ClassMethods
  end

  module ClassMethods
    def guitar
      "gently weeps"
    end
  end
end

class Bar
  include Foo
end

puts Bar.guitar
```

Comment: That's a Rails thing, the question is about pure Ruby.

Comment: @MrYoshiji I didn't set the tags, all I now is that RubyMonk is not about Rails.

Comment: ActiveSupport is only part of rails. You can use it seperately. In addition, that link gives example how to solve your problem.

Comment: @Zhomart That's not the thing. This tutorial is about using the techniques already taught in that very same tutorial.